# Error Running RCP Project in Eclipse

Tags: java, eclipse, eclipse-plugin, eclipse-rcp

I have inherited an existing RCP project, and I am totally new to how this type of project works.

I am running Eclipse IDE for Java Developers (Version: Oxygen.3 Release (4.7.3)).

When I try to run the project as an Eclipse application, I get the following error:

```
java.lang.NullPointerException
    at org.eclipse.e4.ui.internal.workbench.ModelServiceImpl.<init>(ModelServiceImpl.java:122)
    at org.eclipse.e4.ui.internal.workbench.swt.E4Application.createDefaultContext(E4Application.java:511)
    at org.eclipse.e4.ui.internal.workbench.swt.E4Application.createE4Workbench(E4Application.java:204)
    at org.eclipse.ui.internal.Workbench.lambda$3(Workbench.java:614)
    at org.eclipse.core.databinding.observable.Realm.runWithDefault(Realm.java:336)
    at org.eclipse.ui.internal.Workbench.createAndRunWorkbench(Workbench.java:594)
    at org.eclipse.ui.PlatformUI.createAndRunWorkbench(PlatformUI.java:148)
    at org.eclipse.ui.internal.ide.application.IDEApplication.start(IDEApplication.java:151)
    at org.eclipse.equinox.internal.app.EclipseAppHandle.run(EclipseAppHandle.java:196)
    at org.eclipse.core.runtime.internal.adaptor.EclipseAppLauncher.runApplication(EclipseAppLauncher.java:134)
    at org.eclipse.core.runtime.internal.adaptor.EclipseAppLauncher.start(EclipseAppLauncher.java:104)
    at org.eclipse.core.runtime.adaptor.EclipseStarter.run(EclipseStarter.java:388)
    at org.eclipse.core.runtime.adaptor.EclipseStarter.run(EclipseStarter.java:243)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(Unknown Source)
    at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(Unknown Source)
    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Unknown Source)
    at org.eclipse.equinox.launcher.Main.invokeFramework(Main.java:653)
    at org.eclipse.equinox.launcher.Main.basicRun(Main.java:590)
    at org.eclipse.equinox.launcher.Main.run(Main.java:1499)
    at org.eclipse.equinox.launcher.Main.main(Main.java:1472)
```

I have seen some solutions for this issue saying `org.eclipse.equinox.ds` and `org.eclipse.equinox.event` are required to be included in the plugin dependencies, but this has not solved my problem.

Comment: Look the run configuration for the app ( 'Run > Run Configurations' ) and make sure those plugins are included ub the 'Plugins' tab.

Comment: @greg-449 Thanks, they're not included there. However, everything seems to be 'greyed out` and I can't find a way to include them. Any thoughts?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

To solve this issue, I did the following:

1. Delete my Run configuration: Run > Run Configuration, then select the configuration, press big red `x` button, close
2. Created product configuration: File > New > Other, then Plugin Development > Product Configuration, next, select project, provide product configuration filename, finish
3. Product configuration file should be opened automatically (if not, open it), then, select Contents tab, and add the `org.eclipse.equinox.event` plugin
4. Select Configuration tab, add `org.eclipse.equinox.event` to Start Levels and set `Auto-Start` to `true`